# Force vertical white space at top and bottom of page to be _exactly_ the same

Tags: vertical-alignment

I am trying to get exact symmetry of leading and trailing vertical white space.

I have a sample 1-page document with a top line containing the dummy text "ABCDE", some dummy vertical space, and a bottom line, also containing the text "ABCDE". My page size is 8.5in by 11in.

The goal is to get the distance from the absolute top of the page to the top of the letter A in the first line to be exactly same as the distance from the absolute bottom of the page to the base of the letter A on the last line.

I tried the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\begin{document}
\topskip=0pt
\vspace*{\fill}
ABCDE
\par
\vspace{7in}
\par
ABCDE
\vspace*{\fill}
\end{document}
```

but it doesn't quite work.

I want the solution to automatically work for all pages, each with their own amounts of leading and trailing vertical white space. For example, one page may need 4in of leading and trailing space which I want to split as exactly 2in at the top, and 2in at the bottom, and some other page may need only 1.5in of vertical space which I want to split as exactly .75in at the top, and .75in at the bottom.

How can I do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question isn't so clear where you want the space, especially as your example has a page number.  add `\usepackage{showframe}` to see the block in which your `\fill` are acting.

Comment: I meant to turn off page numbers. Thanks, I'll edit the question.

Comment: @David Carlisle: I turned off page numbering, but it still doesn't work -- there's more white space at the top than at the bottom.

Comment: `\pagenumbering{gobble}` (or better `\pagestyle{empty}` ) does not change the space allocated for the page foot, it just leaves it blank.

Comment: It is possible that your measuring strategy is calculating to top of font, rather than top of character. The top of a font is always higher than the height of un-accented capital letters. Likewise, the bottom calculation might be to bottom of font rather than baseline.

Comment: @RobtA: So what you're saying, if I understand it correctly, is that the top of the capital letter A in my first line is not considered by TeX as  the top of the text area, and analogously, the bottom of the capital letter A in the last line is not considered as the bottom of the text area. Do I have it right? If so, what is considered as top and bottom?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. But it may not be the reason for your problem. The "top of the font" is an internal number, which you can see in a font editor. In meny fonts, it is almost exactly at the top of the ring, in the Aring character (because the designer made it that way). And, the bottom of the font is often, but not always, at the bottom of lowercase j. LaTeX does have the capability to distinguish between "where the font is" and "where its letters are," but I am not an expert in that code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `geometry` package to set the margins symmetrically. If you don't want any margins at all:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\usepackage[ 
    %showframe, 
    top=0pt, 
    bottom=0pt,
    paperwidth=8.5in,
    paperheight=11in,
]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\topskip=0pt
\vspace*{\fill}
ABCDE
\par
\vspace{10.5in}
\par
ABCDE
\vspace*{\fill}
\end{document}
```

This package can also be used to set the paper size.

Comment: Thanks a lot -- that works just fine, and very simple, too! Strangely, your version is also off by about 1.5mm, although the excess is now at the top. Ignoring that minor discrepancy, both of the answers posted appear to solve the problem, although yours is simpler, and the paper size comes out at 8.5in by 11in, which is what I need. Thanks again!

Comment: @tex_novice If you are worries about the 1.5mm, maybe try something like `top=-1.5mm` (no warranty, such a hack might break something...)

Comment: I'll try that, but in any case, I think you have all given fine answers. Much appreciated!

Comment: @tex_novice You're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean something like this with no page head or foot, and all content vertically centred.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\makeatletter
\let\@textbottom\vfill \let\@texttop\vfill

\setlength\topmargin{-1in}
\setlength\headheight{0pt}
\setlength\headsep{0pt}
\setlength\footskip{0pt}
\setlength\paperheight{\textheight}
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength\pdfpageheight{\paperheight}}

\makeatother

\pagestyle{empty}
\def\zz{One two three One two three One two three One two three 
One two three One two three One two three One two three 
\par
One two three One two three One two three One two three 
\par
One two three One two three One two three One two three One two three 
\begin{center}\rule{1in}{4in}\end{center}
One two three One two three One two three One two three 
\par
One two three One two three One two three One two three 
\par
One two three One two three One two three One two three 
One two three One two three One two three One two three One two three\par}
\begin{document}
ABCDE
\par
\vspace{7in}
\par
ABCDE
\clearpage

\zz\zz
\end{document}
```

Comment: why would you ever want to do this? :-)

Comment: Haha -- I have my reasons! But thanks very much for your answer. I'm testing it now . . .

Comment: It's almost perfect! It's actually off by about 1.5mm (excess is on the bottom), and I guess I can live with that, but isn't tex supposed allow exact measures using extremely tiny units? Also, when I ran your code, the page sizes (in the pdf file) come out to 8.5in by 7.61in, but I need 8.5in by 11in. How can I fix that?

Comment: just set \pdfpageheight (and \textheight) to whatever you need, tex measurements are accurate to thousands of an inch, but trick is to work out what point it is measuring from @tex_novice

Comment: Cool! I think you've given me all I need to solve this problem, and probably other such issues that may arise in the future. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you want get exact spaces at the top and at the bottom, specify them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[top=0pt,bottom=0pt,letterpaper]{geometry}

\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\topskip}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\vspace*{2in}

ABCDE

\vspace*{\fill}

ABCDE

\vspace*{2in}

\end{document}
```

You can't do it by specifying the space in the middle, because otherwise the space occupied by the text would go in the supposed margins.

[image]

Comment: The only problem with this approach is I don't want to have to measure the pages in advance. I want tex to compute the spacing.

Comment: @tex_novice What do you mean? I can't understand.

Comment: What I mean is for a given page, I don't know that it should be 2in and 2in. And there will be many such pages, each requiring slightly different spacing.

Comment: But maybe I can use that approach. Let's say I always want at _most_ two inches at top and bottom. Can I tell tex to use that a maximum, and shrink it if necessary (symmetrically, of course)?

Comment: @tex_novice What does the space on top and bottom depends on? If you don't tell, it's guesswork.

Comment: It depends on the vertical length of the text area -- all of it, from the top of the top-most black dot of text, the bottom of the bottom-most black dot of text. The leading and trailing vertical white space should split the difference to fill the page.